# How can I get row with some status and latest id in spring repository?

Tags: java, spring-repositories

I have entity Item with fields - id,...,status

How can I write select for get row with last Id?

I tried this

```
Item findTopByStatusDesc(int status);
```

and

```
Item findOneByStatusDesc(int status);
```

Byt it not worked.

```
id name status
1   hz   0
2   hz2  1
3   hz3  1
```

I need get only one row where status = 1 and id latest `3   hz3  1`

I need order DESC and get first row but I can not

Answer (score 2):

You can limit query results -

```
Item findTopByStatusOrderByStatusDesc(int status);
```

Or

```
Item findFirstByStatusOrderByStatusDesc(int status);
```

Ref -

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result